# Handling views and templates

Tags: php, template

My guts tells me that this isn't the proper way to handle views / templates, so that's why I'm asking you what could be done better.

Some background: This application I'm building now is for use in a school project with people that don't have much knowledge of PHP. Therefore I'm not using a framework like Laravel, or implementing a whole template engine, but I'm trying it to keep as simple as possible while still using classes and code separation.

The `homeController`:

```
Class homeController extends BaseController
{

    public function index()
    {
        $this->view->make("common/home");
    }
}
```

The View class:

```
Class View{

    public static $file;

    public function make($file){
        View::$file = $file;
        require_once DIR_VIEW . "default/template.php";
    }
}
```

The template.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Just an title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php require_once 'header.php'; ?>

    <div id="mainContent">
        <?php require_once DIR_VIEW . View::$file . ".php"; ?>
    </div>

    <?php require_once 'footer.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

`BaseController`:

```
class BaseController
{

    public $load;
    public $url;
    public $view;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load = new Loader();
        $this->url = new Url();
        $this->view = new View();
    }
}
```

The files are required by an loader class with this piece of code: (don't know if it ads some relevance)

```
foreach (glob(DIR_LIB . "*.php") as $filename) {
    require_once $filename;
}
```

The problem is probably that i'm using an `static` variable `$file` inside the `View` class. I don't think that that is right, but don't know any better way (besides using `global()`, but I know that that isn't the solution.

What do you think? Is this good enough or not even close?

Note: there will always be 1 file included, so that's why I thought that a simple `require` would succeed.

Comment: And how are you building and accessing the classes?

Comment: Just a tiny nitpick - `Class` should be lowercase, as in: `class homeController extends BaseController`

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, added the `baseController`, do you need something else?

Comment: @jsanc623, didn't knew that. Thought that it had to be upper case. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Thank you for the code. Besides all that Mathlight has pointed out, you have mixed quotes all over your code. You should chose between `"` or `'`: never mix them unless **extremely** necessary. Ben did that mistake too. In my case, I always use `'` because it doesn't have to look for variables and that speeds up the code. This is a micro-optimization, and shouldn't be taken into account. Simply use the quotes you like the most and stick with them through your code.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, Thank you for pointing that out. Didn't knew I was doing that...

Comment: @Mathlight it can be uppercase, lowercase, studly case, mixed case - php doesn't really care (see http://3v4l.org/u2rjV). However, from a community perspective, built-in keywords are typically all lowercase.

Comment: @Mathlight You are welcome. If you really want to use the `foreach` to include all the files, drop it. It won't be safe and it won't keep the order. If file `external.php` depends on the `internal.php`, you will be in serious troubles. Instead, use something like `foreach (self::$files as $file) {require_once DIR_LIB . $file;}` ( `self` points to the class itself). This will keep the order and you can fine-tune it. I would suggest that you define `$files` as `static private`. I don't know if I'm explaining myself in an understandable way.

Comment: @jsanc623 I do know that PHP doesn´t care at all. But it's best to follow any guide lines that the community are also using.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, I do understand you and what your trying to point out. Only thing i don't fully understand: Why should i use an static variable, if it's private? I mean, i just can use `$this->files` or is that some kind of "wrong"?

Comment: @Mathlight It isn't wrong, but `static` properties have the 'advantage' of allowing you to access the same information across multiple instances. For example: `$a=new yourClass(); $b=new yourClass();` If one changes the value, it will change only for that instance. I see it as a 'fake global variable' for all the instances.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel A i see. Didn't knew that static variables where shared across different instances of classes. Learning a lot today

Comment: @Mathlight I used that trick to create a session manager. It really is useful for some other projects, like yours. You should explore it a little bit more. I'm glad you are learning a lot: that means we are helping you to improve.

Comment: Why not use [Smarty Templates with Laravel](https://github.com/lukeforeman/Laravel4-SmartyView)?

Comment: @GregBurghardt, I would love to use Laravel and it's template engine (blade, or smarty), but this is an school project I'm setting up and my team members don't know that much of PHP. So the system has to be as basic as possible and as simple as possible. So no engine's or frameworks because that's way out of there league...

Comment: I thought you said you were using Laravel, sorry about that. I misread the question. You are _not_ using a framework. Ignore my last comment. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're over-complicating it.

First the static variable isn't required, all the variables in the scope of include/require statements are available in the document being included or required.  For example:

FileA.php

```
<?php
$variable1 = "Something";
require_once __DIR__ . "/FileB.php";
```

FileB.php

```
<?php
echo $variable1; // Outputs "Something"
```

So the $view variable will just be accessible in the template.php file.  That said I think your code could be changed up just a bit and be a lot cleaner.  I went through and tweaked it some with comments below.  Feel free to ask any questions you may have after reading through it:

View.php

```
<?php
class View {
    const DIR_VIEW = "/views/";

    function make ($view, $data = array()) {
        extract($data, EXTR_SKIP); // Extracts key/value pairs from data as variables

        ob_start();

        // Just require header here, later on you could add another option to make for layout,
        // to use different headers footers if needed.  Just include everything up to
        // <div id="mainContent"> in the header.php file.
        require __DIR__ . Views::DIR_VIEW . 'header.php';

        // Do this better, it's open to a directory traversal attack: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack
        require __DIR__ . Views::DIR_VIEW . $view . '.php';

        require __DIR__ . Views::DIR_VIEW . 'footer.php'; // Just require footer here

        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

HomeController.php

```
<?php
class HomeController extends BaseController // Capitalize the H
{

    public function index()
    {
        // Add a return, have your router take the action method's return value and echo it.
        // This way your view class isn't just arbitrary printing things out, and will give you
        // flexibility later to have different types of returns (like for redirects you could
        // do Redirect::to('/'), similarly to laravel).

        return $this->view->make("common/home");
    }
}
```

common/home.php

```
<p>Bam! <?php echo $someVariable; ?> Wow! Such Templates!</p>
```

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo isset($title) ? $title : 'Your site'; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="site-nav">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </nav>
    <div id="mainContent">
```

footer.php

```
    </div>
    <footer class="site-footer">
        &copy; Copyright 2014
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This sounds very promising. I'll try to implement it and fiddle around with it. Also i'll leave this question open for just some more time so that others can react to. Maybe they come with some interesting stuff to ( so that i can learn ;P )

Comment: I just have one thing to point out: You are using mixed quotes. Stick into single (`'`) or double (`"`) quotes though your code. I always choose single quotes for performance reasons. But that is a simple micro-optimization and you can safely ignore it. But for readability you should stick with the quotes you prefer.

Comment: Also, my first question regarding your code: `why do you use an const in the View`? I mean this part: `const DIR_VIEW = "/views/";` Why don't U use an `define` or simple `$` variable?

Comment: @Mathlight a `define` creates a global constant. He is keeping the data self-contained. The `DIR_VIEW` will always be the same and won't change in your code. You could use a global constant, but that doesn't give any guarantee that it will actually exist. It also, as a side effect, will increase the consistency of your code. This is my interpretation and I might be wrong about this.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Well, I define it in an `config.php` which is loaded at the very beginning. But besides that, why would that be more consistent then? ( sorry for all these question, but I'm trying to learn the maximum now if possible :D

Comment: @Mathlight If you reuse the class for other project, you don't have to worry if you already defined those constants or not, if there is another with the same name and it makes debugging a little more difficult. If it is contained and 'right there', you don't have to do much: just dump the class on your file and initialize it that the values will always be correct. This is simply the way I see it, and it's purely opinion-based.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel didn't thought about reusing it in an another project. If you put it that way it's obviously smart to do that